# iMac's built-in microphone doesn't work on Windows 8

Tags: bootcamp, microphone, windows

I'm running an up-to-date copy of Windows 8 on my iMac via Boot Camp and apparently it doesn't like the built-in microphone. I tested it with Audacity and Teamspeak, both of them just record absolute silence.

My Mac is a late 2012 27" iMac and I have the latest version of Apple's Boot Camp drivers installed. Is there anything else I can do to make my microphone work with Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'm dumb. For some reason the upper slider was set to 0, effectively silencing the microphone. Setting it to 100 solved my problem.

[image: Properties of my microphone]

Comment: I almost Voted you up but that would mean I agree with you been Dumb :)